# Use l3build check with classes not in dtx format

Tags: l3build

I have inherited a class that I want to modify. This class is just a cls file that calls another cls file. I would like to create some regression test in the process.

The `l3build` documentation handles the case when the class is derived from a dtx file. As my understanding goes, the class file is generated on the fly to run the test (sandboxing?)

When I run the tests, the main class is not found. I guess it is because of the class file not being copied into `build/` folder. I search a way in the `l3build` manual, but I don't find a way to set the build system without the dtx files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `sourcefiles` and `installfiles` to the 'pre-unpacked' sources, usually something like

```
sourcefiles = {"*.cls", "*.sty"}
installfiles = sourcefiles
```

and optionally you can turn off entirely the unpacking step

```
unpackfiles = { }
```

This will mean that `l3build` will copy your files as-is, both the the build folder and to the testing one.